# Qt Drag and Drop QListView removing the item on which it is released

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qlistview

I working on a small QlistView which is Sortable.

```
    iListView = new QListView(this);
    //Creating a standard item model
    iStandardModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    
    //First item
    QStandardItem* item1 = new QStandardItem(QIcon(":/cover-story-album-art.jpg"),"First Item");
    //Second item
    QStandardItem* item2 = new QStandardItem(QIcon(":/cover-story-album-art.jpg"),"Second item");
    //third item 
    QStandardItem* item3 = new QStandardItem(QIcon(":/cover-story-album-art.jpg"),"Third item");
    
    //Appending the items into model
    iStandardModel->appendRow(item1);
    iStandardModel->appendRow(item2);
    iStandardModel->appendRow(item3);
    
    //Setting the icon size
    iListView->setIconSize(QSize(40,30));
    
    //Setting the model
    iListView->setModel(iStandardModel);
    
    //Setting listview geometry
    iListView->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,240,320));
    iListView->setDragEnabled(true);
    iListView->setAcceptDrops(true);
    iListView->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

Well the Drag and Drop works but there is a issuse if i drop the item on the any other item replaced other than the end of the list.The "dragged" item replaces the "released up on" item.

**Screen shot of QListView  at different Scenarios**
[image: Screen shot of QListView at different Scenarios]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because by default `QStandardItem` has `Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled` flag set. Just remove it by using `QStandardItem::setFlags()` function. Add following lines:

```
item1->setFlags(item1->flags() ^ (Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled));
item2->setFlags(item2->flags() ^ (Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled));
item3->setFlags(item3->flags() ^ (Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled));

iListView->showDropIndicator(); // For convenience..
```

Comment: item1->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled); isn't doing the job

Comment: You're suppose to `reset` it not `set` it. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Any suggestion on how i can made it work like http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/.I mean when you remove the item there is a vaccum space that moves with the dragged item.Thankz